# The multiple carousel does not implementing in a right way

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having problems with multislider. It does not slide.The objects that needs to be shown on slider, appears as in grid format. Website, where I have integrated a slider: [Website](https://shahar.uz/)

The deal is that the slider divides objects into two rows, while in a working mode, everything has to be in one row and should move to the right and left sides.

[image]

Here is **html** code that i used:

```
 <div class="MultiCarousel" data-items="1,3,5,6" data-slide="1" id="MultiCarousel"  data-interval="1000">
                            <div class="MultiCarousel-inner">
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="pad15">
                                      
                                    </div>
                
                                </div>
                            </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code is provided below:

```
 .MultiCarousel { float: left; overflow: hidden; padding: 15px; width: 100%; position:relative; }
.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner { transition: 1s ease all; float: left; }
.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item { float: left;}
.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item > div { text-align: center; padding:10px; margin:10px; background:#f1f1f1; color:#666;}
.MultiCarousel .leftLst, .MultiCarousel .rightLst { position:absolute; border-radius:50%;top:calc(50% - 20px); }
.MultiCarousel .leftLst { left:0; }
.MultiCarousel .rightLst { right:0; }

.MultiCarousel .leftLst.over, .MultiCarousel .rightLst.over { pointer-events: none; background:#ccc; }
```

Comment: your multislider.css is not found. Maybe your include path is wrong

Comment: Each slider item should be in it's own `<div class="item">`, you have all 6 within a single `<div class="item">` so that are all treated as a single item/slide.

Comment: @2pha I have corrected it, but still slider does not slides. I do not know what`s the problem.